# Mersenne number and quadratic residue $\pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ a prime number. Let define $M_p=2^p-1$ and $q$ a prime divisor of $M_p$. First I have to prove that $p\ \vert \ (q-1)$.

Notice that we have $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and also $2^p\equiv 1 \pmod q$. Moreover by little Femat we have $2^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod q$. That means that $p=k(q-1)$ but it is not the result. I probably missed something.

Then I must deduce that if $q\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $p\ge 3$ then $2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod q$.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factors_of_Mersenne_Numbers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thank you but why $2^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 2qk \pmod p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first part, it seems to me that you're almost there!

Since $2^p \equiv 1$ (mod $q$), as you point out, we have $2^p = 1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z})^\times$ (the multiplicative group of invertible elements modulo $q$). This means that $\text{ord}(2) \mid p$ --- either $\text{ord} (2) = 1$ or $\text{ord} (2) = p$. Since the first case is not possible, $\text{ord} (2) = p$. Now since $2^{q-1} = 1$ as well in $\mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z}$, we know that $\text{ord}(2) \mid q-1$, ie. $p \mid q-1$.

Comment: Thank you and for the second part ?